# Deleting a predicate from a knowledge base

Tags: prolog

I would like to pose a question. I have a knowledge base that I am working on and I want the user to delete a predicate that he wants by using delete_predicate.

The knowledge base is something like this:

```
is_tired(erin).
is_tired(mary).
```

I have defined delete predicate as

```
delete_predicate(Predicate):-tell('my_knowledge_base.pl'),
    retract(Predicate),
    told.
```

Let's say that the user wants to delete the predicate is_tired(mary). He will enter the following query:

```
?-delete_predicate(is_tired(mary)).
```

And the given predicate will be deleted form kb. 
I tried the the aforementioned rule but it deletes all kb's contents!!

I would really appreciate any pointer!

I will show exactly how I need the delete_predicate to work.

Let's assume I have the aforementioned knowledge base enriched with some more predicates:

```
:-dynamic(tired/1).
tired(kosta).
tired(renata).
tired(jim).
tired(mom).
tired(sister).
tired(mother).
tired(uncle).
tired(me).
```

If the user wants to delete tired(mom). from the kb he will query this:

```
?-delete_predicate(tired(mom)).
```

Then, the knowledge base will have that predicate deleted and it will look like this:

```
tired(kosta).
tired(renata).
tired(jim).
%here used to be the tired(mom).
tired(sister).
tired(mother).
tired(uncle).
tired(me).
```

If the user wants to delete tired(me) from the kb then the kb will be:

```
tired(kosta).
tired(renata).
tired(jim).
%here used to be tired(mom).
tired(sister).
tired(mother).
tired(uncle).
%here used to be tired(me).
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

retract/1 actually works:

```
?- findall(X,is_tired(X),L).
L = [erin, mary].

?- delete_predicate(is_tired(mary)).
true.

?- findall(X,is_tired(X),L).
L = [erin].
```

but I think you are trying to store in 'my_knowledge_base.pl' the retracted predicates.
Because you don't write nothing between tell/told the file remains empty.

You could do instead

```
delete_predicate(Predicate) :-
    open('my_knowledge_base.pl', append, S),
    (  retract(Predicate)
    -> format(S, '~q.~n', [Predicate])
    ;  true % what about errors?
    ),
    close(S).
```

then the file will contain the deleted facts.

**edit** Actually I didn't understood the question: a possibility could be

```
delete_predicate(Predicate) :-
        open('my_knowledge_base.pl', append, S),
        format(S, ':- retract(~q).~n', [Predicate]),
        close(S).
```

**edit** we can test if retract succeed before appending the :- retract(Predicate) to the file. Using the syntax you prefer

```
delete_predicate(Predicate) :-
  (  retract(Predicate)
  -> append('my_knowledge_base.pl'),
     format(':- retract(~q).~n', [Predicate]),
     told
  ;  true % or fail?=
  ).
```

Comment: Hi there! Actually what I want is that when a user deletes a predicate I want it to be removed from the knowledge base. The retract  modifies the knowledge base in memory, it doesn't affect the actual pl file.
Is there a way I can delete from the actual pl file the predicate the user wants gone?

Comment: appending ':- retract(Predicate).' to the file should work. The file will also need the :- dynamic declaration...

Comment: Unfortunatelly that doesn't work either..! I had already declared my predicate as dynamic through :-dynamic(tired/1). I appended to the file as you suggested but nothing happens to the pl file.

Comment: I've tested, seems to work. After the call the file contains :- retract(...) near the end and after reconsult there is just 1 fact... Maybe need to check operational details...

Comment: This is the content of my knowledge base:
`:-dynamic(tired/1).
tired(kosta).
tired(renata).
tired(jim).
tired(mom).
tired(sister).
tired(mother).
tired(uncle).
tired(me).

delete_predicate(Predicate):-append('retract_predicates.pl'),
        retract(Predicate),
        told.`
After the delete_predicate the pl file remains intact. However if I query listing(tired) the predicate is no longer in the memory but it exists on the file...!

Comment: try `delete_predicate(Predicate):-append('retract_predicates.pl'), retract(Predicate), format(':- retract(~q).~n', [Predicate]), told.`

Comment: The solution provided doesn't work as I want to. 
With your solution if I query `delete_predicate(tired(me)).` it adds `:- retract(tired(me)).` in my knowledge base which is not what I want. As explained in my question I want to delete the predicate from the kb NOT to add the predicate that the user wants to delete.

Comment: what about a condition, like that I used in the first answer (i.e. `(retract(Predicate) -> format(...) ; true)`. See last edit...

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. When I query delete_predicate(tired(mom)),or anything for that matters, I get Undefined Porcedure error! These are the exact contents of my pl file `:-dynamic(tired/1).
tired(kosta).
tired(renata).
tired(jim).
tired(mom).
tired(sister).
tired(mother).
tired(uncle).
tired(me).

delete_predicate(Predicate) :-
  (  retract(Predicate)
  -> append('retract_predicates.pl'),
     format(':- retract(~q).~n', [Predicate])
     told ;  true).`

Comment: err..! that is embarassing...I added the comma.I did try what you suggested but it doesn't work as I want it to. After quering `delete_predicate(tired(mom)). delete_predicate(tired(me)). delete_predicate(tired(uncle)). the following are added to the knowledge base:
`:- retract(tired(mom)).
:- retract(tired(me)).
:- retract(tired(uncle)).`
I want the the predicates tired(me), tired(mom) tired(uncle) to be deleted/erased/gone from my knowledge base as stated earlier.
I really appreciate your help chac.

Comment: if retract/1 succeeds, it delete from *memory* db, then we append to file (it's your knowledge base, I think) the required command. What's not working? Maybe your knowledge base has a different name? you are using modules and retract need to be qualified? We should not use comments to detail the question, or we'll get banned...